# Java WebStart fails on Mac OS Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java

After searching several hours for a helpful hint on support pages and FAQs that really (!) work this question:

I need Java WebStart for an application that works on MAC OS X (Mountain) Lion. So far we had no problem with the application on Snow Leopard.

On my MacBookAir the applications starts. On a second system with the same OS and the same Java installations I always receive the well known  error window (with the corresponding English message like "you have to load the Java Runtime  Environment for Web Start...)

A click on "more information" delivers the java.com web page that offers the JRE download that is already installed.

The corresponding console error message is:

```
"No Java Web components present, requesting install"
```

System: Mac OS X 10.8.2, Intel Core Duo

Installed Java:

- Apple 1.6.0_37-b06-434
- Oracle Java SE  Run Time environment:7u9)
- Oracle Java SE jdk-7u9-macosx-x64.dmg)

Output of 
   /usr/bin/java -version 
is: Java SE runtime environment 1.7.0_09-b05

The java.com website signals on the installed version web page): Version7 Update 9 installed.

The Java Control Panel also says:

"Version 7 Update 9 installed"

The Java Control Panel offers no choice to "enable the Java web start".

Any suggestion is very welcome!

Best regards,
Werner

Answer (score 1):

The oracle java version here (1.7.0_09-b05) is old and  is  blocked by Safari as a security risk a see this [Apple note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5648). Upgrade to the current [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which is currently Java SE 7u21.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and the following apple suport entry helped me to solve my problem: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Check also the links on the bottom saying "To re-enable the Java 7 applet plug-in".

Comment: Thank you for your post. Would you be willing to summarize the instructions from the link? It is fine to have links in answers, it is just best that the answer be self-contained - allowing future visitors to understand. Links can change, break, or any number of things.